# OIDC: Keep access tokens valid during long-running server operations

Tags: http, token, refresh, openid-connect

If a user authenticates via OpenID Connect on a client and triggers a long-running server-side request, how can the server keep the access token valid if the operation takes longer than the access token's expiration time?

We have an application suite consisting of several server-side backend applications (typically accessed via REST, HTTP, and/or WebDAV), several web frontend applications and several client-side (i.e. desktop) applications. We already support the Basic and Kerberos/Negotiate authentication schemes and are currently adding support for OpenID Connect.

Our backend applications are typically accessed by the web frontend and client applications, other server-side backend applications, and 3rd party customer applications when our software is integrated into their system. We currently pass OpenID access tokens via the Bearer scheme to the backend applications.

In a typical scenario, a user (authenticated on a local client or in a web frontend) triggers a server-side operation which may possibly run for several minutes, hours, days, or even weeks. This operation accesses other backends on the user's behalf, e.g. a Web-DAV based server-side file system, to access additional data. All backend applications need the user's authentication information to grant access and access further user details for authorisation (e.g. to only grant access to the user's own files).

Obviously, this means that the access token provided with the original backend call may expire before the operation is completed. The server therefore needs a way to refresh the access token without user interaction. Our code can already do this if it knows the user's refresh token (using the refresh token and the application's client ID and secret to access the OIDC Token endpoint).

But how can we "correctly" pass the refresh token to the server?

The client has (potentially) the full set of ID, access, and refresh tokens. But from what I understand, the Bearer scheme expects that the passed token is the access token. Compatibility is important here, since our backend applications may also be accessed by 3rd party client applications. Assuming that getting the refresh token into the server application is the correct approach at all, we therefore still have to support situations where the caller can only provide an access token (with the obvious implications that in these cases, long-running operations will not be able to access other backend services on the user's behalf).

I could imagine the server accepting either an access token or a refresh token via Bearer. But from what I understand, the only "argument" a client may pass with a correct Bearer authentication header is a single Base64 encoded string, i.e. the (access) token. The client could pass an access or refresh token here, but I don't see how the server could then tell which it is, as to my knowledge both token types are opaque.

I understand that the original idea is for server operations to be short lived, so that keeping the access token up to date is the client's responsibility. But surely we cannot be the first who do need to combine OIDC with long-running server-side operations. Is there an accepted way to pass a refresh token to a server, or, alternatively, a completely different approach that I'm missing?

Comment: I'm also researching this question. I appreciate this question is a few years old. One comment. Passing a refresh token could cause problems. If you have refresh token rotation (using refresh token revokes it and returns a new one) and refresh token reuse detection (not uncommon), then refresh tokens become single use for increased security. Hence passing a refresh token to a backend process means now client and backend service try to use the same refresh token, only one will succeed.